# How to store an array from a form in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I have a form some thing like

```
<form>
              <label class="label">Class Name</label>
              <label class="input">
                <input type="text" name="class_name[]">
              </label>
            </section>
            <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-5">
                <label class="label">Grade</label>
                <label class="input">
                  <input type="text" name="grade[]">
                </label>
</form>
```

I want to store this in my mongodb database.
I am using a schema like

```
var SchoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 classroom: [{
        Name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        grade: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        }

    }]
});
```

Please suggest me how I can save the data from form in this database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register you SchoolSchema to mongoose first

```
mongoose.Schema.model('School', SchoolSchema);
```

Then, at your controller:

```
var School = new mongoose.Schema.model('School');

exports.submit = function(req, res) {
  var classRooms = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < req.body.class_name.length; i++) {
    classRooms.push({Name: req.body.class_name[i], grade: req.body.grade[i]});
  }
  School.create({classroom: classRooms}, function(err, school) {
    ...
  });
};
```

Note: Please follow NodeJS / Javascript conventions

Comment: Hi, there is little error i am getting in storing these values using above method. Only a single entry is being made in the database and of the form "a,b,c" whereas there should be three entries made with data a b and c

Comment: Can you edit your question to compare the expected & real output at db?

Comment: When I am using the solution you provided I am getting this result in db =>[{ Name: a,b ,Grade: 1,2}]  ,whereas it should to be => [{Name:a ,  Grade:1}, {Name:b, Grade:2}].